# Multiple database application ACL (part 2)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, acl

I posted this question [Access Control with a multi database application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352857/access-control-with-a-multi-database-application)
So I tried putting it into application. Here is the case. I have a mainDB that has an ACL with no roles defined. The User clicks a button and it opens a control for CRUD with a datasource that has a computed filepath to a different database call it appDB. In appDB the ACL has several roles defined, and I have added myself to the ACL and assigned me the roles [Admin] and [Finance]. In this control I have added an After Page Load event that does the following:

```
var roles = context.getUser().getRoles();
viewScope.put("vsRoles", roles);
```

Upon opening the page the viewScope vsRoles is [] so it has not recognized that I have an additional set of roles in the appDB. So it would appear that context.getUser().getRoles() only gets my roles at authentication time when I log into the mainDB.nsf, and is not picking up the roles when I open appDB. I need to use the roles to configure what actions a person can perform, plus which documents a user can read and/or edit.

To complicate the issue the user may switch between multiple target application databases and will no doubt have different roles and access to each one. 
thanks for the response to my previous question,but I might not have explained it in enough detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as far as I understood, what you need is to learn what specific roles the user has for the appDb.

`context.getUser().getRoles()` provides information about the current application (mainDB.nsf in your case). You are accessing appDB.nsf at a data source level. You can use a java method to learn the roles of a specific user in a target database:

```
public static List<String> getRoles(Database targetDb, String userName) {
    ACL acl=null;
    List<String> roles=new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        acl=targetDb.getACL();
        roles.addAll(targetDb.queryAccessRoles(userName));
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // failed, nothing to do...
    } finally {
        if(acl!=null) acl.recycle();
    }

    return roles;
}
```

As an example:

```
Session session=ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
Database appDb=session.getDatabase("", "appdb.nsf");

// Make sure appDb is not null...

List<String> roleList=getRoles(appDb, session.getEffectiveUserName());
ExtLibUtil.getViewScope().put("vsRoles", roleList);
```

Comment: @Serdan thanks that should do the job. I have a number of buttons on the page and I use the persons role to determine which ones are displayed. I have not done it yet but I am assuming that if I have a role in a Reader or Author field in the appDB that those would be enforced based on the assignment role in appDB. Will have to do some more testing.
--> Thanks

Comment: I was able to add this to a Bean that I already have that handles the application Properties so in fact I do not need to pass anything to the getRole method.
public List<String> getRoles() {
    List<String> roles=new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
     Session session=ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
        String userName = session.getEffectiveUserName();
     roles.addAll(this.getAppDB().queryAccessRoles(userName));
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // failed, nothing to do...
    }
    ExtLibUtil.getViewScope().put("vsRoles", roles);
    return roles;
}
getRoles could not be static.

Comment: Making it static or not depends on your implementation. I use a separate utility class for such methods, so I can reuse them on different databases.